# Function that takes a string of letters, outputs a list of words from a Valid Word List then finds the word with the highest scrabble score

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, data-structures

I've been trying to build a function that takes a string of letters, outputs a list of words from a Valid Word List then finds the word with the highest scrabble score from this list

I have designed a function that outputs all possible words from a string, a function to calculate scrabble scores from a list of words and a function that outputs the highest score

However, I am struggling to:

1. Combine the three (to calculate the output list with the highest possible score)
   and
2. Return a list containing all possible words with this second word generating function, currently, it outputs words in separate lists

**Function that calculates scrabble score**

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0 # Create score var
    for i in word: # Loop through given word
        total += score[i.lower()] #Lookup in dict, add total
    return totaldef charCount(word): 
    dict = {} 
    for i in word: 
        dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1
    return dict
```

**Function that outputs possible words**

```
def possible_words(lwords, charSet): 
    for word in lwords: 
        flag = 1
        chars = charCount(word) 
        for key in chars: 
            if key not in charSet: 
                flag = 0
            elif charSet.count(key) != chars[key]: 
                    flag = 0        #for word in word_list:
        if flag == 1: 
            #word_value_dict = {}
            firstList = []
            #word_value_dict[word] = get_word_value(word, letter_values)
            firstList.append(word)
            #return word_value_dict
            print(scrabble_score(word), (word))
            print(firstList)if __name__ == "__main__": 
    input = ['goo', 'bat', 'me', 'eat', 'goal', 'boy', 'run'] 
    charSet = ['e', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'l', 'b'] 
    possible_words(input, charSet)
```

**Function that can find the word with the highest score from a list**

```
 def score(word):


        dic =  {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
          "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
          "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
          "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
          "x": 8, "z": 10}
        total = 0
        for char in word:
            total += dic.get(char.upper(), 0)
        return total
    #return highest score
    def best(lista):
        return max(lista, key=score)best(['goo', 'bat', 'me', 'eat', 'run'])
```

Current Output:

```
4 me
['me']
5 goal
['goal']
```

Desired output: A list of all possible words

```
['me', 'goal']
```

OR A dictionary (or similar structure) with possible words as keys and score as values

```
{'me':4, 'goal':5]
```

AND the word with the highest score

```
'goal':5
```

I need a way of returning a list from the first function, and combining the two to find the highest score in that list

Stay awesome

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your scrabble_score function, there is some formatting error. Please correct that

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it works absolutely perfectly 

I've been meaning to thank you - you're a legend 

If there is anything i can ever do for you - 0742 9191 217

Comment: Currently I'm working through this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201580/reformatting-fields-as-columns-other-fields-paired-with-the-fields-to-become-c

My plan is to create lots of small pivot tables, on for each column/question-answer pair then concatenate, then self-join

Only problem is there's a mixture of datatypes in the column so pivotting is not working for some of the columns

Comment: Haha, thats a little too much gratitude! :) You can accept the answer then (tick mark below the voting section of the answer) to acknowledge it as the solution. Meanwhile, let me see if I can help with your other question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your function definitions. I have copied the corrected version below, with comments wherever I have modified something:

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0
    for i in word: 
        total += score(i.lower()) # Changed square brackets to normal brackets
    return total 

def charCount(word): 
    dict = {} 
    for i in word: 
        dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1
    return dict

def score(word):
    dic =  {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
      "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
      "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
      "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
      "x": 8, "z": 10}
    total = 0
    for char in word:
        total += dic.get(char.lower(), 0) # Change .upper() to .lower() or else it will return only zero
    return total 

def possible_words(lwords, charSet): 
    firstList = {} # Made this a dictionary instead of list
    
    for word in lwords: 
        flag = 1
        chars = charCount(word) 
        for key in chars: 
            if key not in charSet: 
                flag = 0
            elif charSet.count(key) != chars[key]: 
                    flag = 0       
        if flag == 1: 
            firstList[word] = scrabble_score(word) # Adding to the dictionary
    print(firstList)
    best(firstList)

def best(lista):
        print("Best word is '{}' with score {}".format(max(lista, key=score), lista[max(lista, key=score)])) # Changed as per requirements
```

Using the above function definitions and the following input:

```
input_words = ['goo', 'bat', 'me', 'eat', 'goal', 'boy', 'run'] 
charSet = ['e', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'l', 'b']
```

my output for `possible_words(input_words, charSet)` is as follows:

```
{'me': 4, 'goal': 5}
Best word is 'goal' with score 5
```

,which is as desired.