# Reformatting fields as columns, other fields (paired with the fields to become columns in the previous structure) to become fields in the new columns

Tags: python, excel, database, data-cleaning, data-munging

Ive been tasked with cleaning data from a mobile application designed by a charity

In one section, a users Q/A app use session is represented by a row. This section consists of repeated question answer field pairs, where a field represents the question asked and then the field next to it represents the corresponding answer. Together, each question/field and answer column pair represent a unique question with the answer.

Starting data

```
    answers.0.answer    answers.0.fieldName answers.1.answer    answers.1.fieldName
5   0                    avoidexercise             0.0            vomitflag
6   156                  height                    54.0         weight
7   1                    affectedkneeside           3.0       painlocationknee
```

I have been asked to reformat the section so each question forms a column, the corresponding answer a field in that column

The ideal output

```
_id                    avoidexercise    enjoyment   fatigue2weeks   height
        

5f27f29c362a380d3f9a9e46    1.0           yes            20.0       120.0
5f27f2ac362a380d3f9a9e4b    0.0           no             40.0       180.0
5f27f4d4362a380d3f9a9e52    1.0           yes            50.0       150.0
```

My plan is to create many pivot tables, from each other Q/A pairs of columns, then concaternate (outer join) then inner join to remove duplications

However, the original dataframe contains a mixture of numeric and object datatypes

Therefore, only some question/answer column pairs appear to be converting to pivot tables. I have tried using various aggregate functions

```
p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
p2 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.1.fieldName'],values=['answers.1.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
p3 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.2.fieldName'],values=['answers.2.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
I have also tried another lambda function

p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x)
The furthest I have got so far is to run pivots with standard mean aggfunc

p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns=['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'])
ps = [p1,p2,p3]
c = pd.concat(ps)
```

Then attempting to remove merge rows and columns

```
df = c.sum(axis=1, level=1, skipna=False)

g = df.groupby('_id').agg(np.sum)
```

This returns a dataframe with the right shape

However, it looses the values in the object columns, and I'm not sure how accurate all the numeric columns are

To overcome this problem, I was considering converting as much data as I can into numeric

```
c4 = c.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').info()
```

Then splitting the combined pivot table dataframe into numeric and object type

```
nu = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
cndf = c4.select_dtypes(include=nu)
o = ['object', 'bool', 'datetime64', 'category']
codf = c4.select_dtypes(include=o)
```

And running through the same .sum and groupby operations as above on the numeric dataframe

```
n1 = cndf.sum(axis=1, level=1, skipna=False)
n2 = n1.groupby('_id').agg(np.sum)
```

However, this still leaves the challenge of dealing with the object columns

Comment: Hi, its not possible to reproduce a dataframe from an image as you have provided. Please refer this answer to understand how to include reproducible pandas code in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/11130170

Comment: I see, I've typed up the frames Ishwar

Comment: Thanks, I have posted an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to obtain your desired result:

First define the number of question-answer pairs you have:

```
num_answers = 2 #Following your 'Starting data' in the question
```

Then use the following couple of lines to obtain a dataframe as required:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.concat([pd.pivot_table(df1, index=['_id'], columns= ['answers.{}.fieldName'.format(i)], values=['answers.{}.answer'.format(i)]) for i in range(num_answers)], axis = 1).fillna('N/A')
df2.columns = [col[1] for col in df2.columns]
```

Here `df1` is assumed to be your dataframe with the starting data.

As you might have noticed, 'N/A' is present in cells where the particular id has no recorded answer for that particular field.

Assuming an ID of [1,2,3] for the three rows respectively, the output `df2` for your 'Starting data' would look like this:

```
      affectedkneeside  avoidexercise   height  painlocationknee    vomitflag   weight
_id                     
0          N/A                0           N/A         N/A              0         N/A
1          N/A               N/A          156         N/A              N/A       54
2           1                N/A          N/A          3               N/A       N/A
```

Comment: Hey Ishwar, 

I really like this 

However, unfortunately the original dataframe had mixed data, so I ham getting a DataError: No numeric types to aggregate when I attempt to contacternate all 68 pairs

Comment: Also I love your code, could I pay you a quid for every solution you have?

Comment: How about we use apply somehow 

ur.iloc[:,5:136:2].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1)

This just tells us weather or not a user has answered a question 

Would it be possible to use a different method to .valuecounts()

Comment: This is an open forum, so you dont need to pay :) ! You can upvote and accept answers if it helps you, that would do :)

Comment: I am not sure if the .iloc approach would work!

Comment: Well, I certain respect and appreciate your genius

Any ideas on how we could merge the object columns together